# What is the windowing logic of function tmsum in DolphinDB?

Tags: window, moving-average, dolphindb

Take the first example in [tmsum](https://docs.dolphindb.cn/en/Functions/t/tmsum.html#ariaid-title4) as an example.

```
tmsum(1 1 3 5 8 15 15 20, 5 2 4 1 2 8 9 10, 3)
// output
[5,7,11,5,2,8,17,10]
```

Why does the summing calculation in the window of the element “5“ return 5, shouldn’t it be 7 (2+4+1)? Is there an illustration to explain the windowing logic of `tmsum`?

Answer (score 0):

For the windowing logic of `tmsum`, you may refer to the illustration in [Time-Based Moving Functions (tm-functions) (dolphindb.cn)](https://docs.dolphindb.cn/en/Functions/Themes/tmFunctions.html).

Windows that involve time-series data slide based on the time units. In your example, since parameter T of `tmsum` is of integral type, the range of the corresponding window is (Ti - window, Ti].

The window of the first element “1“ is (-2, 1], which contains the value “5“;

The window of the second element “1“ is (-2, 1], which contains values “5“ and “2“;

The window of the third element “3“ is (0, 3], which contains values “5“, “2“, and “4“;

The window of the fourth element “5“ is (2, 5], which contains the values of elements “3“ and “5“, that is “4“ and “1“;

The window of the fourth element “8“ is (5, 8], which contains the values of only the element “8“, that is “2“;

and so on…